# Join decrypted column to select query from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains an encrypted column that can be returned with sample query below

```
select dbo.clrdecrypt (tax_ID '{0C70XXX4}')
  FROM [dbo].[T1])
```

Please is it possible to return results of entire table and including the decrypted column?
This is what I have attempted but getting error below. Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT  
       [field1]
      ,[field2]
      ,[field3]
      ,[field4]
      ,[field5]  
,(select dbo.clrdecrypt (tax_ID '{0C70XXX4}')
  FROM [dbo].[T1]) AS TAX_ID

  FROM [dbo].[T1]
```

> **ERROR:** Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,
> <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: as the error message stated, it is due to your subquery `select dbo.clrdecrypt (tax_ID '{0C70XXX4}'` returns more than 1 value

Comment: Its the same table, so can't you just do `SELECT [field1], [field2], [field3], [field4], [field5], dbo.clrdecrypt (tax_ID '{0C70XXX4}') TAX_ID FROM [dbo].[T1]`?

Comment: [Docs has examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#Scalar)

Comment: @DaleK Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked. Not sure why I was over thinking it. Thanks once again.